# How to compute the expected value of the following game

Tags: probability

It's a drinking game, I would like to know the expected ammounts of drink a player would get.

Rule (for a N step version of this game. Normally N=3, but why would we not like to generalize?):

At each step, the player must flip a coin and guess the outcome, if he guess correctly he goes to the following step, if not, the must drink $2^{Step-1}$ drinks and he starts over. The game ends when the player arrives to the Step N.

Mathematically (or algorithmically) written:

Drinks = 0;

i=0;

while $i<N$

Throw a coin and choose heads or tail.

If (guessed correctly)

i = i + 1;

else

Drinks = Drinks + 2^i;

i = 0;

end

end

Which would be the expectated value of Drinks for a balanced coin?

Answer (score 1):

The probability of reaching step $N$ in a round is $2^{-N}$ so the expected number of rounds to reach step $N$ is $2^N$, and the expected number of failed rounds is $2^N-1$.

Given that a round is a failure, the expected number of drinks is $\dfrac{1\times \frac12 + 2\times \frac14+4\times \frac18+\cdots+2^{N-1}\times \frac{1}{2^N}}{ \frac12 +  \frac14+ \frac18+\cdots+ \frac{1}{2^N}} = \dfrac{N}{2}\times \dfrac{2^{N}}{2^{N}-1}=\dfrac{N\,2^{N-1}}{2^{N}-1} $.

So the expected number of drinks in total is $(2^N-1)\times \dfrac{N\,2^{N-1}}{2^{N}-1}= N\,2^{N-1}$

For $N=1$, this is $1$.  For $N=2$, this is $4$. For $N=3$, this is $12$.